# Flex - Compiling and linking lex.yy.c with the "-lfl" library to produce an executable a.out

Tags: windows, gcc, flex-lexer

FLEX reads a specification of a scanner either from an input file *.lex, or from standard input, and it generates as output a C source file lex.yy.c.

I run this command from windows CMD and generate lex.yy.c successfully:

```
> flex inputfile.lex
```

Then, lex.yy.c should compile and link with the "-lfl" library to produce an executable a.out. 
I dont know how to run this command from windows command line...

```
> gcc lex.yy.c -lfl
```

This error occurs: 'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What should I do? Thanks

Comment: You don't have `gcc` installed or it is not in your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you have your .lex file in c:/user/flex means you have also include gcc.exe inside the folder.That helps to solve your error.and also to produce a.out

**gcc -o a lex.yy.c -lfl** try this

Answer (score 0):

Set your envoirnment variable for gcc 
This will work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you make your answer a bit more verbose, e.g. why will this fix the problem?